# Is it possible to iterate through documents stored in Lucene Index?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have some documents stored in a Lucene index with a docId field.
I want to get all docIds stored in the index. There is also a problem. Number of documents is about 300 000 so I would prefer to get this docIds in chunks of size 500. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
IndexReader reader = // create IndexReader
for (int i=0; i<reader.maxDoc(); i++) {
    if (reader.isDeleted(i))
        continue;

    Document doc = reader.document(i);
    String docId = doc.get("docId");

    // do something with docId here...
}
```

Comment: Without the isDeleted() check, you would output id's for documents that had been previously deleted

Comment: To complete comment from above. Index changes are commited when index is reopen so reader.isDeleted(i) is necessary to guarantee that documents are valid.

Comment: @Jenea what is the equivalent method in Java for checking whether the document is already deleted or not? i am looking for similar functionality.. i dont want to consider the document which is already deleted.

Comment: The IndexReader.isDeleted() is gone since at least 2010 (Git changeset 6a4bfc796fea6ed3474350adb271e06275d22e6a). Definitely not present in Lucene 4.x.

Answer (score 19):

**Lucene 4**

```
Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(reader);
for (int i=0; i<reader.maxDoc(); i++) {
    if (liveDocs != null && !liveDocs.get(i))
        continue;

    Document doc = reader.document(i);
}
```

See LUCENE-2600 on this page for details: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html

Comment: This was rolled back by another user but the original editor was correct, liveDocs can be null

Comment: These days (Lucene 8.x), that would be `MultiBits.getLiveDocs(reader)`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a query class named [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html), I think it can be used in this case:

```
Query query = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
TopDocs topDocs = getIndexSearcher.search(query, RESULT_LIMIT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Document numbers (or ids) will be subsequent numbers from 0 to IndexReader.maxDoc()-1. These numbers are not persistent and are valid only for opened IndexReader. You could check if the document is deleted with IndexReader.isDeleted(int documentNumber) method

Answer (score 0):

If you use .document(i) as in above examples and skip over deleted documents be careful if you use this method for paginating results.
i.e.: You have a 10 docs/per page list and you need to get the docs. for page 6. Your input might be something like this: offset=60,count = 10 (documents from 60 to 70).

```
    IndexReader reader = // create IndexReader
for (int i=offset; i<offset + 10; i++) {
    if (reader.isDeleted(i))
        continue;

    Document doc = reader.document(i);
    String docId = doc.get("docId");
}
```

You will have some problems with the deleted ones because you should not start from offset=60, but from offset=60 + the number of deleted documents that appear before 60.

An alternative I found is something like this:

```
    is = getIndexSearcher(); //new IndexSearcher(indexReader)
    //get all results without any conditions attached. 
    Term term = new Term([[any mandatory field name]], "*");
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);

    topCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.create([[int max hits to get]], true);
    is.search(query, topCollector);

   TopDocs topDocs = topCollector.topDocs(offset, count);
```

note: replace text between [[ ]] with own values.
Ran this on large index with 1.5million entries and got random 10 results in less than a second.
Agree is slower but at least you can ignore deleted documents if you need pagination.