# Forgot to close the Lucene IndexWriter after adding Documents to the index

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, full-text-indexing

I had a program running for 2 days to build a Lucene index for around 160 million text files, and after the program ended, I tried searching the index and found the index was not correctly built, indexReader.numDocs() returned 0. I checked the index directory, it looked good, all the index data seemed to be there, the directory is 1.5 Gigabytes in size.

I checked my code and found that I forgot to call indexWriter.optimize() and indexWriter.close(), I want to know if it is possible to re-optimize() the index so I don't need to rebuild the whole index from scratch? I don't really want the program to take another 2 days.

Comment: How do you know, index was corrupt? try opening in LUKE http://www.getopt.org/luke/ , see if it can show the Documents!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `IndexWriter.optimize()` is not necessary and can be called at a later time by reopening the index. It just optimizes the documents in the index for better read performance and doesn't otherwise affect anything.

If you forgot to call `IndexWriter.close()` however then your index might not be complete. Since you processed so many documents it likely flushed most of them, so hopefully you only need to re-index the last ones. Use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) as suggested for a UI to quickly browse the index to see what state it's in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I need to re-index all the files, cause I have no idea what documents are not flushed, I need the index to be exact.

Comment: You could iterate through the documents in the index to determine which ones exist before you re-index everything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311845/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-documents-stored-in-lucene-index