# Lucene NRTManager handling

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to understand how Lucene should be used.

From what I have read, creating an `IndexReader` is costly, so using a `Search Manager` shoulg be the right choice. However, a `SearchManager` should be produced by a `NRTManager`(which, by the way, should replace the `IndexWriter` for every add or delete operation performed). But in order to have a `NRTManager`, I should first have an `IndexWriter`, and here comes my problem.

The documentation says:

- an IndexWriter is thread-safe
- the constructor of this class takes a `Directory` object, so it seems creating an instace should be costly(as in the case of an IndexReader)
- all changes are buffered and flushed periodically(so they seem to encourage using a single instance)

  but:
- the changes, although flushed will only be visible after `commit` or `close`
- after finished making updates(add/delete), the instance should be closed
- I also found this: [Forgot to close the Lucene IndexWriter after adding Documents to the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374419/forgot-to-close-the-lucene-indexwriter-after-adding-documents-to-the-index) where it is said that not closing a writer might ruin everything

So what am I really supposed to do? Is having a single `IndexWriter` instance a good idea(make only `commit` and never `close` it)?

What is more, if I use `NRTManager`, how can I make a `commit`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html) will probably help you understand how to use NRTManager and SearcherManager. It explains how to handle `commit`s and `reopen`s in a near-realtime context.

Regarding your IndexWriter questions, yes, using a single IndexWriter is encouraged, but you always need to close your IndexWriter at some point. Closing an IndexWriter will perform several things:

- wait for the current merge operations to finish (optional),
- commit pending data,
- remove the directory lock file.

This is why documents might not be visible if the IndexWriter was not closed whereas there were still pending changes to the index.

In a long-running application, you should close your IndexWriter when the application exits (in a desktop application, this can be done when the users closes the application, and in a webapp, this can be done in the destroy method of a servlet).

Comment: Thank you, great articles on that blog. It made me realise that I don't need a NRTManager(in my case it only over-complicates things). As for the closing of the IndexWriter, I'll folow your advice.