# How to get all documents of lucene index?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have created a lucene index .

I would like to get all documents that just according to a field sorting and no search terms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know your Lucene versions match but the answer at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311845/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-documents-stored-in-lucene-index) may work for you. See [2](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Iterating-over-all-documents-in-an-index-td2480114.html) for another thread including another approach.

[Is it possible to iterate through documents stored in Lucene Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311845/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-documents-stored-in-lucene-index)
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Iterating-over-all-documents-in-an-index-td2480114.html

Answer (score 14):

Please specify `q=*:*` as a search term

Answer (score 13):

The class `MatchAllDocsQuery` looks like what you need to retrieve all documents: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user2720864 I think you misunderstood my answer, which started with "How about ..". That was no critique. It was a real suggestion on how to solve the OP's problem. To make it clearer, I rephrased it to remove that expression. Besides the writing style, this is not only a proper answer (they don't always need to be long) but also a very correct answer (unless you can disprove it).

Comment: best answer for this question