# List all the documents in a Lucene 4 index

Tags: java, lucene

I want a list of all the (path of the) documents contained in a given Lucene 4 index.

According to [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html), (see item Lucene-2600) the code to use is

```
import org.apache.lucene.util.Bits; 
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;

Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
if (!liveDocs.get(docID)) {
// document is deleted...
}
```

But, the [getLiveDocs documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiFields.html#getLiveDocs%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader%29) states `liveDocs` can be null.

What happens in that case? Is there really no easy way to list the documents in a index?

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311845/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-documents-stored-in-lucene-index/18499503#18499503)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
int maxDoc = indexReader.maxDoc();
for (int doc=0; i<maxDoc; i++)
{
     Document d = indexReader.doc(doc);
     ...
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure that the document is not deleted?