# Accessing documents marked for deletion

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack, pylucene

Is there any way to access documents marked for deletion that are still present in segments?

If not via Elasticsearch's REST API, then perhaps using Lucene to iterate through documents some way (kind of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321781/4574048) answer maybe)?